# What is this? MySQL array?

Tags: mysql

In my phpMyAdmin, one meta term, have this value:

```
{a:1:{i:0s:82:"http://parquedasfeiras.online/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/alefit-e1576791796664.jpg”}}
```

What is this? MySQL array type?

Comment: This is an array serialized by PHP (converted to string). Look at examples [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress stores meta and option values in a [serialized format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) if they are objects or arrays.

So what you have there is an array (`a`) with an integer (`i`) key `0` and a string (`s`) value with `82` characters.